# How can i fill in all the blanks in Column B using the data found in Column C

Tags: vba, excel, filter

I have completely rewritten my original question, i hope this is okay as far as Stack Etiquette?

(That was not a 3rd question)

```
       ****SAMPLE DATA****

Date        Order           Reference Field 1
06/03/15    **865754iFP 002**   
06/03/15    **865754iFP 002**   
06/03/15    **818013Dc6 002**   
06/03/15    **817660RiV 004**   
06/03/15                     **920488Hgg 001**
06/03/15                     **920488Hgg 001**
06/03/15    **123771Pq2002**    
06/03/15    123712p1 001
```

In the example data above you see 3 headers, Date; Order; Ref. Field 1. 
(Col,s A,B,C, Rows 1-8)

There are orders in both columns. Those numbers are the ones I am highlighting **bold** in my workbook.

I have removed the data that would normally fill spaces. (In my workbook there are 28 columns and hundreds of rows of data.)

I'm trying to make something to recognize all of the **Bold** cells and merge them into one Cell. You'll notice that where there is no **Bold** cell in column A, there is **Bold** in column B of the same row. Where and in what form it will happen is a variable. There will always be a **Bold** cell in every row.

This is the order number, and I i need to find all the order numbers on the sheet, where ever they may be, highlight them, and put each one into column C, but in the same row it is found in.

The workbook already runs a code that locates, highlights, and cleans these order numbers, so they are all in the same basic structure I need them to be in the final sheet. For example; 123456ABC; 6 numbers, followed by either 2, or 3 characters(Alpha/Num).

Now my problem is just merging them into one column; or maybe the term would be copying them into one column.

Fill in all the blanks in Column B using the data found in Column C. In my workbook the orders are highlighted with a gray fill, not bolded font.

Comment: Could you provide sample of the data, to get more clear understanding what you trying to achieve?

Comment: VasilyI edited my post in response to your comment

Comment: so, you want to move data from column `C` to column `B` if cell in column `B` is empty and cell interior color for column `C` is grey?

Comment: If Column C has a cell with Gray interior color, i need to move it to Column B same row, which may or may not be empty.

Comment: Only cells with the data i need are highlighted gray. They can be found in column B or C, but i want them all in C. So there will be rows in both columns that do not have the data i need, and are not highlighted gray. i just want all the gray to be in one column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i correctly understand what you need, then you can use this:

```
Sub test()
    Dim n&, cl As Range, temp$
    n = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For Each cl In Range([B2], Cells(n, "B"))
        'if B grey and C grey
        If cl.Interior.ColorIndex = 15 And cl.Offset(, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 15 Then
            cl.Value = cl.Value & "; " & cl.Offset(, 1).Value
            cl.Offset(, 1).Value = "": cl.Offset(, 1).Interior.Pattern = xlNone
        'if B not grey and C grey
        ElseIf cl.Interior.ColorIndex <> 15 And cl.Offset(, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 15 Then
            cl.Interior.ColorIndex = 15: cl.Offset(, 1).Interior.Pattern = xlNone
            temp = cl.Offset(, 1).Value: cl.Offset(, 1).Value = cl.Value
            cl.Value = temp
        End If
    Next cl
End Sub
```

`colorindex` can be replaced by another one color, depending on color you use

*data before run macro:*

[image]

*data after run macro:*

[image]

Comment: Yes!!!, i altered it to suit the actual columns i am using which are S and AC. And i did remove the "if B and C are grey" I just needed the if B not grey and c grey, it syncs up. Thank you so much, a wonderful help, and hard to explain, so truly wonderful!

Answer (score 0):

You would need to apply filter on each used column i.e. find the last used column index and use for-loop to apply the filter as you're already doing till last column.

You may use below code to find index of last used column and use to loop through.

```
Public Function LastColumn(Optional wks As Worksheet) As Long
  Dim wks As Worksheet
  Set wks = ActiveSheet
  LastColumn = wks.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
  After:=wks.Range("A1"), _
  Lookat:=xlPart, _
  LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
  SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
  SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
  MatchCase:=False).Column
End Function
```

Comment: Hi Akif,Sorry for the late reply to this. Where do i put this function?